# run program in all user logon in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I have program called popup.exe. I know I can kill program in all user logon in Windows with the command `taskkill /im popup.exe /f`.

The question is how to run popup.exe in all user logon in Windows after I run `taskkill /im popup.exe /f`?

Comment: What is the purpose? Windows only allows one active session at a time. So there are other way to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to accomplish other than what you have suggested. But, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i have popup.exe to show popup from my program thar run as service. If i am update my program I am kill popup.exe and run popup.exe again. If i run update my program and there is 3 user logon on Windows, popup.exe only run again in 1 user Windows and not  run in 2 another user Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Workstation versions of Windows only allow one active user session at a time. So, having `popup.exe` restart on all user sessions at the same time is not necessary.

Instead, you could start it when a particular user session becomes active. Such as when you switch users on the computer.

You can do this with a scheduled task using ["On connection to user session"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841(v=ws.11).aspx) trigger. Then `popup.exe` can run whenever a user session becomes active.

Otherwise, you should re-write your service to properly interact with the desktop of the active user session.

Comment: On connection to user session is not available for tasks that are configured for Windows XP. My client use Windows XP. Do you have another way?

Comment: @YosJuandaLinggarjati please [edit] your question to indicate you're running XP.

Comment: If i logon in 1 user and i have 3 user Windows, how to create scheduled task in all user Windows?